# SQL Search Query With Null and ''

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, null

I have a query that I'm building for an application.  The database is setup in SQL Server 2008.  I want to use a query similar to below, however, I will be using this 'Where' clause for about 4 other columns using the same requirements.  Is this the appropriate way to test for null or '' in a column that is VarChar(255) and does allow nulls.

Ideally, if the variable @UutSerialNumber is null or empty (''), I want all the results, but if it is not, I want to use the 'LIKE' clause.  Is this the proper way of doing this and will it work?  It seems to work until I start adding more columns to the Where clause.

Also, how would I handle a "text" datatype using the same type of query?

`SELECT DeviceName, UutStatus
FROM MyTable
WHERE (UutSerialNumber LIKE '%' + @UutSerialNumber + '%' OR UutSerialNumber LIKE '%%' AND (@UutSerialNumber = '' OR @UutSerialNumber IS NULL)) AND ...`

Help is appreciated.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: What do you expect with this filter: `OR UutSerialNumber LIKE '%%'`?

Comment: I was under the impression it would mean select everything.  Therefore, if there the parameter is null or '', then don't filter on that column.

Comment: But you have that on a `OR`, so if `UutSerialNumber` has some value (and that is different from selecting everything, since that doesn't count the `NULL` values), then it won't be filtered, independent of the value of your parameter

Comment: You should avoid the `text` datatype if at all possible. Can you use `varchar(max)`?

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with the the 'text' datatype.  It is only for one column, but part of the query nonetheless :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It amy seem like duplication of SQL but the best way to do this is in terms of performace is using IF ... ELSE

```
IF ISNULL(@UutSerialNumber, '') = '' 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  DeviceName, UutStatus 
        FROM    MyTable 
        -- MORE EXPRESSIONS
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  DeviceName, UutStatus 
        FROM    MyTable 
        WHERE   (UutSerialNumber LIKE '%' + @UutSerialNumber + '%' 
        -- MORE EXPRESSIONS
    END
```

It can be done within the WHERE clause if you are doing it on multiple columns and the query you posted wasn't far off it was just missing additional parenthesis along with having a redundant clause.

```
SELECT  DeviceName, UutStatus 
FROM    MyTable 
WHERE   (ISNULL(@UutSerialNumber, '') = '' OR UutSerialNumber LIKE '%' + @UutSerialNumber + '%')
AND     (ISNULL(@AnotherParameter, '') = '' OR AnotherColumn LIKE '%' + @AnotherParameter + '%')
```

Convert the text type to VARCHAR(MAX).

as a footnote, I personally would use the CHARINDEX rather than concatenating strings in the like:

```
WHERE   (ISNULL(@UutSerialNumber, '') = '' OR CHARINDEX(@UutSerialNumber, UutSerialNumber) > 0)
```

This is nothing more than a footnote however as I have done no performance testing, I just think it is easier on the eye!

Comment: Won't the conversion to Varchar be very expensive in terms of efficiency if you are querying say 100k rows?  Any workarounds?

Comment: Alter the table structure so that the column is stored as varchar(max) thus removing the need for a conversion? Text and nText are obselete and will be removed from future versions of SQL, so for future proofing it is worth changing the column data type anyway.

Comment: The database I'm using for this I cannot modify.  There are restrictions on this database since it is used for live data beyond my control.

Comment: The no work arounds that I can think of then, I don't think the conversion to varchar(max) will cause a significant drop in performance on 100k rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DeviceName, UutStatus 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ((@UutSerialNumber = '') OR (@UutSerialNumber is null)) OR (UutSerialNumber like @UutSerialNumber)
```

add '%' to the last @UutSerialNumber if you think you need

Comment: this seems to work how i wanted it to.  excellent.  However, how do I use this query for a "text" column.  It doesn't seem to accept text as an input parameter.

Comment: the text datatype you mean? try casting it as varchar.